# How to prevent a simple anchor/link propagating to the parent?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

Say I want a simple `a` link within a `div` that itself has an `on-tap`:

```
<div id="wrapper" on-tap="{{doSomething}}">
 <p>Something unlinked.</p>
 <p><a href="http://woven.co" target="_blank">Something linked.</a></p>
</div>
```

The `a` is propagating/bubbling to the parent event, but I'd like to prevent that. In code, I can listen for clicks and `e.preventPropagation` but in code I've found it difficult to get a link to simply open in a new tab like the `a` + `target` method above would do.

Most often I'm using `on-tap` and not `a` and so it's not as common of a need as it might seem, but it still seems like a simple ask.

What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to add an `on-tap` alongside the `a href` which calls a method that stops propagation of the event:

```
<div id="wrapper" on-tap="{{doSomething}}">
 <p>Something unlinked.</p>
 <p><a href="http://woven.co" target="_blank" on-tap="{{stopProp}}">Something linked.</a></p>
</div>
```

The method:

```
stopProp(Event e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

The click on the `a` still opens the link in a new tab as expected, only now the event doesn't propagate/bubble up to the parent event.